# Writing UserRecord object to firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have a cloud function to write user data to my firestore when a new user is created

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();


exports.addNewUserToCollection = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

    // if we don't do this song and dance we get the following error
    // Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.
    var userData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));

    return db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(userData);
});
```

my question is around setting the data for the document.
event.data according to the docs is a UserRecord object.
When i console log it, it looks like a javascript object but if i attempt to set it directly i get

> Error: Argument "data" is not a valid Document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.

So I've resorted to doing stringify and then parse.

**Is there a better way i should be doing this?**

Answer (score 2):

To be able to save the user data you will need to reduce the object passed to `event.data` to just its (JSON) data. According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#access_user_attributes), the `event.data` argument is a `UserRecord`. If you look at the [reference document for `UserRecord`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord) it has a `toJSON()` method that seems to be precisely what you need.

Comment: except it doesn't. If I call toJSON() on the event.data it throws an error toJSON() is not a function. the UserRecord itself looks to be a plain javascript object but it isn't and it is missing the toJSON() call.